# UWP and URL navigation

Tags: c#, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

Here is my C#

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var url = "http://" + Ip + "/GET NOWORNEXT EPG { \"count\" : \"30\", \"group\" : 6, \"epgNowOrNextFlag\" : \"1\", \"startIdx\" : \"0\" } ";
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This code is working on PC, also is working on mobile emulator, but the problem is with device (Lumia 950)

On the PC and mobile emulator I get the response `200 (OK)`

However on the mobile device I get `301 Moved Permanently`

I cant seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247072/uwp-getting-http-301-in-windows-mobile is your?

Comment: Try to debug and get in response location url where it moved. Probably for WP it needed slash at the end of url